# Using Firebase Reserved Hosting URLs in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using TypeScript to implement firebase app, and there are four ways to initialize firebase app according to [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries).

I'm successful when using firebaseConfig object, but using "Reserved Hosting URLs" I can't seem to get away from this message:
`Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

What I'm doing is the following:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/database";

... (inside of Component)

ngOnInit() {
  var testRef = firebase.database().ref('test');
  testRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log('test', snapshot.val());
  });
}
```

I'm guessing that firebase.database() is likely getting invoked before firebase.initializeApp() code, but I can see that `<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>` has been loaded successfully without an error, which contains the following:

```
if (typeof firebase === 'undefined') throw new Error('hosting/init-error: Firebase SDK not detected. You must include it before /__/firebase/init.js');
firebase.initializeApp({
  "projectId": "....",
  "appId": "....",
  "databaseURL": "....",
  "storageBucket": "....",
  "apiKey": "....",
  "authDomain": "....",
  "messagingSenderId": "...."
});
```

I've placed the `<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>` in an appropriate place, in the body tag, as suggested by the documentation. **Is there anything else I need to do additionally to make this work with TypeScript, and be able to use firebase.database() anywhere within the Component?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize Firebase before any other call to one of its component.

You may get the config from the reserved url in an async/await function like that:

```
const load = async () => {
   let config = {}
   const response = await fetch('/__/firebase/init.json')
   config = await response.json()

   ...
```

then pass the config object to `initializeApp()` and proceed with the rest of your app bootstrapping.

Comment: Thanks for your idea! It's kind of interesting that we have to call initializeApp() twice, through init.js as mentioned by the firebase, and through the method above. I wonder if it's best practice, but at least it works :)